# Convert Hive result Set to Multi-Character delimited CSV - SelectHiveQl Processor NIFI

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, apache-nifi, jdbctemplate

I am trying to fetch big full table with 10M+ records from hive using selectHiveQL Processor and did find that the converttoCSVStream() method in the source code takes longer time than fetching the result set . 
Observing the code : Result set is being iterated row by row and then added to the output stream .

When the table size is small it completes the process in seconds but as the data is large it takes longer time . Is there any way we can optimize the conversion ?? 
I have tried with the fetch size of 100000/1000/10000/1000 .

Here is the code :

```
while (rs.next()) {
        //logger.info("+++++++++++++Inside the While loop+++++++++++++++++");
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.processRow(rs);
        }

        List<String> rowValues = new ArrayList<>(nrOfColumns);

        for (int i = 1; i <= nrOfColumns; i++) {
            final int javaSqlType = meta.getColumnType(i);
            final Object value = rs.getObject(i);

            //logger.info("+++++++++++++Entering the Switch at +++++++++++++++++");
            switch (javaSqlType) {

                case CHAR:
                case LONGNVARCHAR:
                case LONGVARCHAR:
                case NCHAR:
                case NVARCHAR:
                case VARCHAR:
                    String valueString = rs.getString(i);
                    if (valueString != null) {
                        // Removed extra quotes as those are a part of the escapeCsv when required.
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        if (outputOptions.isQuote()) {
                            sb.append("\"");
                            if (outputOptions.isEscape()) {
                                sb.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(valueString));
                            } else {
                                sb.append(valueString);
                            }
                            sb.append("\"");
                            rowValues.add(sb.toString());
                        } else {
                            if (outputOptions.isEscape()) {
                                rowValues.add(StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(valueString));
                            } else {
                                rowValues.add(valueString);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        rowValues.add("");
                    }
                    break;
                case ARRAY:
                case STRUCT:
                case JAVA_OBJECT:
                    String complexValueString = rs.getString(i);
                    if (complexValueString != null) {
                        rowValues.add(StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(complexValueString));
                    } else {
                        rowValues.add("");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if (value != null) {
                        rowValues.add(value.toString());
                    } else {
                        rowValues.add("");
                    }
            }
            //logger.info("+++++++++++++Exiting the Switch at +++++++++++++++++" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }


        // Write row values
        //logger.info("+++++++++++++Writing Row value at+++++++++++++++++" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        outStream.write(StringUtils.join(rowValues, outputOptions.getDelimiter()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        outStream.write("\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        nrOfRows++;


        if (maxRows > 0 && nrOfRows == maxRows)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: why not to use writer(utf8) over output stream? instead of writing to `stringbuffer` and then using `string.join` - write directly to output. check that stream is buffered... maybe you can split one query to several ones with smaller resultset and run them in parallel.

Comment: also check if it's possible to set fetch size for your driver https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10982

Comment: @daggett this code snippet is from the tool's Java code which is in place .  
Fetch size can be set and as I have mentioned I have tried with different fetch sizes as well .

Comment: `tool's java code in place` - what do you mean? you can't modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

Improvements to SelectHiveQL's CSV output are covered in [NIFI-5307](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5307) but have not yet been implemented. There has also been discussion (but no Jira that I know of) to allow incremental commits (i.e. sending out partial results as soon as they have been processed rather than sending all when the result set has been fully processed) such as has been done in QueryDatabaseTable ([NIFI-4836](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4836)).